# displaying subcategories under the categories in oscommerce

Tags: php, mysql, list, categories

Here is the markup of what I have so far:

```
<?php

$categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.categories_image, c.parent_id, c.sort_order, c.date_added, c.last_modified from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.categories_id = cd.categories_id order by c.sort_order ASC");
while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)){

echo '<tr class="dataTableRow">
<td class="dataTableContent">' . $categories ['categories_name'] . '</td>';
?>

<td class="dataTableContent"></td>

<?php
echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

This displays all the categories and subcategories all on a page, but in no order, what i need is for the subcategories to be displayed under the main category. I have some clue as to how i would do it, a link between the `sort_order` field and the `parent_id` field. The main categories use the `sort_order` field as id, and the subccat's use the `parent_id` field to sort the category they belong to. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do display category tree with single MySQL query, so I'm suggesting to use recursive PHP function:

```
<?php
    function showChildCategories($parent) {
       $parent = intval($parent);

       // Select only categories with parent_id = $parent
       $categories_query = tep_db_query("select 
               cd.categories_name,
               c.categories_id
           from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . 
               TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd 
           where c.categories_id = cd.categories_id 
                 and c.parent_id = $parent
           order by c.sort_order ASC");

       // Go through all query result rows
       while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)){
           // Show category name
           echo '<tr class="dataTableRow"><td class="dataTableContent">' . 
               $categories ['categories_name'] . '</td></tr>';

           // Show child categories for current row
           showChildCategories($categories ['categories_id']);
       } // while
    } // function showChildCategories

    // Show top-level categories and all their children recursively
    showChildCategories(0);
?>
```

Comment: Ive used your given suggestion, it seems to ahve worked but I am getting an error saying `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare showChildCategories() (previously declared in ..\(filename:43) on line 43` Any ideas to what this means?

Comment: Its alright, i got it fixed. Thanks for the suggestion alexkorep